# Issue with saving data using mysql_query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am using this php code to save order details.

```
public function saveShippingDetails($factoryid,$date,$noOfPlaces,$jsonStr){

        $result = mysql_query("insert into shipping_details(FKFactoryID,shippingDate,NoOfPlaces) values('$factoryid','$date','$noOfPlaces')");

        //check for successful store
        if($result){
            //get shipping details
            $detailsID = mysql_insert_id();//last inserted id
            $result1 = mysql_query("select * from shipping_details where shippingDetailsID=$detailsID");

            $count=0;

            $arrjson = json_decode($jsonStr,true); //gets the parent json object
            $length = sizeof($arrjson['places']);
            for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
                $city = $arrjson['places'][$i]['city'];
                $longitude = $arrjson['places'][$i]['longitude'];
                $latitude = $arrjson['places'][$i]['latitude'];
                $result2 = mysql_query("insert into delivery_places(FKShippingDetailsID,city,longitude,latitude) values('$detailsID','$city','$longitude','$latitude')"); //line 1
                if($result2){
                    ++$count;
                }
            }
            if($count==$length){
                return mysql_fetch_array($result1);
            }else{
                return false;
            }               
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But the insert part of line1(commented) has not been saved in the db. Though I get the return values with `$detailsID`, which means the condition of `($count==$length)` becomes true as well.I checked the  `delivery_places` table, but the data has not been saved. What is the issue?

**I hosted the scripts in 000webhost**

Thanks.

Comment: What returns `mysql_error()` after this line/query? What returns echo `insert into ...`?

Comment: i am not getting any error. I get the return values. I checked the sql statement also and it inserted values as well. so the query is also ok.

Comment: When you put query with values directly to PMA, Adminer, etc., the data are saved into database?

Comment: yes, The query is correct

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try using the `mysql_commit()` function. It might be possible that the data is inserted but not commited to the database.

Either that or before beginning the inserts,put this condition:

```
mysqli_autocommit($con,TRUE);
```

If there is no error, I can only think that data is not getting commited.

I am not familiar with PHP's syntax to connect to mysql but shouldn't you mention the connection variable also in the `mysql_query()` function?

Comment: I am getting 0 value for array size. dont know the reason??

Comment: Hey! $result1 = mysql_query("select * from shipping_details where shippingDetailsID=$detailsID");                                                                             In this line you need to enclose $detailsID in '  ' like other php variables. So try your function with this: $result1 = mysql_query("select * from shipping_details where shippingDetailsID='$detailsID'");